# corona sdk does not support mp3 play?

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I hope to use Corona sdk to develop a new game.
But I can not find out the api playing mp3 file.
Does Corona sdk support playing mp3 stream?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not streaming, yet, but will play mp3. CoronaSDK is pretty awesome.

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/mediaplaysound

Answer (score 2):

Actually, media.playSound() has been deprecated. Corona SDK now has OpenAL audio implemented, and there's tons of audio and playback related features. Here's the documentation page for the new OpenAL audio API in Corona:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/audio